# Main Menu disconnected

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsmenuitem

I have been working on a Cocoa app that has been working great until today for some reason the all of the items in the Main Menu has become disconnected form their actions.  Is there a simple setting I accidentally clicked upon that would do this?  I am new to Cocoa/OS X programming and have been working in iOS for the last 3 years.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does "disconnected" mean...if you open the NIB file, are the connections just gone now?  If the connections are still there, it could be that something else is now taking precedence.  See the Cocoa documentation for details but basically a command can be implemented by a number of objects and the first one in the chain "wins".  For instance, the `NSApplication` may implement a method, or the application's delegate, or the active `NSWindow`, or its `NSWindowController`, or the active `NSView`, among others.

Comment: The menu items were "hooked up" to various commands within the First Responder and App Delegate and were all working.  For example the Quit command was connected to the terminate: command in the First Responder. Now it is no longer assigned.  I can reassign it easily enough but I am curious as to why all of the menu items have lost their associations. I have several custom menu items as well that perform specific tasks as well.  Now all of the assignments have been removed.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would happen; a corrupted file, perhaps.  If you have revision control for your project (such as `git` or `svn`) you could try comparing the current file against a past version and see what is different, and when it changed.

Comment: This is ultimately what I did.  I suspect the file became corrupted but I am not sure why. Oh well.  Alls well that ends well.